# Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bits) not recognize 8GB SDHC memory card Kodak

Tags: kodak

I have a 8GB SD HC memory card. Kodak. I plugged but it isn't recognize. I tried restarting and the same result. I'm new in Ubuntu. What I should do? Thnks.

Comment: Does your hardware support SDHC or only plain SD?

Comment: (In the Terminal) The output of `lsusb`?

Comment: I use a partition with Win 7 and i can read the memory.  With terminal lsusb: Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf2:6230 ENE Technology, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04ca:0022 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:08a2 Logitech, Inc. Labtec Webcam Pro

Answer (score 0):

Try the Disks manager: It will show you if either the card reader isn't connected or the card isn't recognized or no partition is detected.

Comment: The card reader is right. I have win 7 partition and the memory is good. I can read, write in memory in win7. But I cannot see the memory in ubuntu.